# Does 4 byte Nonce enough to proof of work?

Tags: blockchain, hash, proof-of-work, nonce

Is it always possible to find an hash value of a block, smaller than the current difficulty, just using 4 byte (Nonce) ? How can we be sure about it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we be sure that a new block will be found?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22978/5406)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not enough.

There is extra-nonce field. The scriptSig of coinbase transaction.