# how long does it take to get 6 confirmations with confidence of 99%

Tags: confirmations

I had this question in an exam but I was not very sure how to solve it:

Suppose Bob the merchant wants to have a policy that orders will ship within x minutes after receipt of payment. What value of x should Bob choose so that with 99% confidence 6 blocks will be found within x minutes

Do you have in idea about the formula that we have to use to find the answer?

Comment: It's a [Poisson process](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_1_2_basic_concepts_of_the_poisson_process.php).

Answer (score 2):

The following holds for a generalized case on the required time for having `m` blocks with a confidence of `p 100\%`. The time `X` between consecutive blocks is exponential distributed, i.e. `X~Exp[k]` with `k=1/10`.
The sum of `m` independent and identical exponential random variables follows the Erlang distribution, that means for `X_i~Exp[k]`,  `X_1+X_2+...+X_m~Erlang[m,k]`. The required time for having `m` blocks with a confidence of `p 100%` is given by the `p`-quantile of the `Erlang[m,k]` distribution. In your case `m=6` and `p=0.99`. The quantile `Q_Erlang[m,k](p)` does not have a closed form expression. However, it is given in terms of the inverse regularized gamma function which can be evaluated numerically.

Plugging in the values leads to `Q_Erlang[6,1/10](0.99)=131.085`, which means that in `99%` of all cases `6` blocks will be mined in less than `131` minutes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It looks like the answer is much more advanced than my level :)
Is there any formula for Q_Erlang that I can use to calculate values for different parameters on calculator?
I mean how can I calculate the value of Q_Erlang[6,1/10](0.99) on a calculator?

Comment: @Digi An online source for the evaluation of the quantiles is https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Quantile%5BErlangDistribution%5B6,+1%2F10%5D,+0.99%5D

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Same result as [stat_facts](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/52598/5406), but another way of explaining it. ;)**

Discovery of blocks is a [Poisson process](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22978/5406).

The probability that `x` blocks are found in the time that we expected `λ` blocks to be found is:

[image]

Now, you have specified that you want to have six blocks found with a confidence of 99%.

The sum of probabilities of all possible outcomes always is 1. This means that we can express the probability of all outcomes where *at least* six blocks have been found as "100% minus the probability of having found less than six blocks".

```
p(x≥6|λ) = 1 - p(5|λ) - p(4|λ) - p(3|λ) - p(2|λ) - p(1|λ) - p(0|λ) = 0.99
```

Plugging the `x` values into the above formula we get:

[image]

The resulting probability curve looks like this (y-axis is probability and x-axis is λ):

[image]

Finally, you were asking for `p(x≥6|λ) = 0.99` which turns out to be at about `λ ≈ 13.1085`. Since the expected time for one block is 10 minutes, this means that in 131 minutes for 99% of the cases at least six blocks will have been found.